# Uniqueness of limit for a Cauchy problem solution

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

i'm trying to prove that if $x(t_n) \rightarrow x^*$ and $x(s_n) \rightarrow x^{**}$ for $(t_n)$ and $(s_n)$ two divergent sequences then $x^* = x^{**}$, where $x(t)$ is the solution of the following problem:
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\dot{x}(t) = - \nabla \varphi(x(t))\\
x(0) = x_0
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Please note that $\varphi:R^n\rightarrow R$ is in $C^{1,1}$ (differentiable and $\nabla \varphi$ is Lipschitz-coninuous) and is also convex.

Any tips on how to prove it? Detailed explanation are also welcome.